# input style doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a useful jQuery code, unfortunately its working great in Firefox but not in IE can anyone tell what was the problem and how to make the same action in IE too.

Thanks,
Paul

My Code is given below

HTML

```
<input name="status" id="status" value="Type something here" type="text"/>
```

CSS

```
#status{
        width:150;
        padding:5px;
        outline:none;
        height:20px;
    }
    .focusField{
        border:solid 2px #73A6FF;
        background:#EFF5FF;
        color:#000;
    }
    .idleField{
        background:#EEE;
        color: #6F6F6F;
        border: solid 2px #DFDFDF;
    }
```

JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').addClass("idleField");
    $('input[type="text"]').focus(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("idleField").addClass("focusField");
        if (this.value == this.defaultValue){
            this.value = '';
        }
        if(this.value != this.defaultValue){
            this.select();
        }
    });
    $('input[type="text"]').blur(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("focusField").addClass("idleField");
        if ($.trim(this.value == '')){
            this.value = (this.defaultValue ? this.defaultValue : '');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you might want to state which version of IE it's not working in also

Comment: @NeXXeus, I mean the on focus effect.

Comment: input[type="text"] <--- this does not select in IE

Comment: @Joe, I See and tried anotherway that J.T.S suggested but too not working in IE

Comment: Seems to work quite fine in IE7/8 through [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MxY6r/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var $input = $("#status"),
            defaultVal = $input[0].defaultValue;

        $input.addClass("idleField");

        $input.focus(function() {

            $input.toggleClass("idleField focusField");
            if ($input.val() === defaultVal) { $input.val(""); } 
            else { $input.select(); }

        });

        $input.blur(function() {

            $input.toggleClass("focusField idleField");
            if ($.trim($input.val()) === "") { $input.val(defaultVal); }

        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: this is a copy (basically) of @J.T.S. answer

Comment: How's that? I changed up a lot of your code and didn't even see his answer before I posted.

Comment: Btw ... what I posted WORKS.  I tested in FF4, IE8, and IE7.  I copied your HTML and CSS, exchanged your jQuery for mine, and it works.

Comment: I was in the middle of writing out all the code and testing it when there were 0 answers is my point.  Not to mention I re-factored his code a bit.

Comment: And when I was using [your] and [his] I was referring to the OP, Paul.

Comment: re-factored again to use `toggleClass` once instead of `removeClass()` twice

Comment: @Scott thanks for the edited one, I wondering I cant see any hope maybe my IE havent support JQuery ..?

Comment: @Paul jQuery is a cross browser library, it's supposed to work in IE. What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: @Pekka it seems that css styles(.focusField and .idleField) not working thats all.

Comment: @Paul it seems to work fine in @Effata's JSFiddle linked above. The problem must be elsewhere. Strange....

Comment: @Paul - The above solution works in both IE7 and IE8 for me.  I tested it myself.

Comment: @Paul - In IE7 and IE8, with the above solution, I get a grey box with a darker grey border for `.idleField` and a lighter blue box with a darker blue border for `.focusField`.  Is that not what you are expecting?

Comment: @Paul - [Here is a working copy out on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5W9YE/) and if you want a version that already includes the document ready as a part of the defaults for jsFiddle view it in this [update](http://jsfiddle.net/5W9YE/1/).

Comment: @Paul - Awesome! Glad you got it going.  Don't forget to mark as answer to help others.

Answer (score 2):

i see you want to put the labels into the inut box. i think this is good, but there is a better and more "XHTML" solution:

i think it would be better if you use default the  tags and then if javascript enabled, hide them and copy into the input box.

my code:

```
(function($){
  /**
   *  This function moves the input <label> into the input field
   *  Creates a new input box with jquery clone, and changes the type to text, so the password fields label will be also visible. on focus and blr only the new input field will hided or shown, depended on the value of the original field.
   *  Example of usage:
   *  @code
   *    $("input#foo").inputLabel();
   *  @endcode
   *  
   *  @require jquery.js
   *  @param none
   *  @return none
   */
  $.fn.inputLabel = function() {
    var input = this
    var id;
    var label;
    var value;
    var isDefault;
    var fake;

    id = input.attr("id");                  //get the id of the input
    label = $("label[for="+id+"]").hide();  //search for the label and hide it
    value = label.html();                   //get the label text

    fake = input.clone();
    fake.attr("type","text");
    fake.attr("value",value);

    input.after(fake);
    input.hide();


    isDefault = true;

    var checkDefault = function() {
      if(input.attr("value")=='') {
        isDefault = true;
      }
      else {
        isDefault = false;
      }
    }

    fake.focusin(function() {
      if(isDefault) {
        fake.hide();
        input.show();
        input.focus();
      }
    });

    input.focusout(function() {
      if(isDefault) {
        input.hide();
        fake.show();
      }
    });

    input.keydown(function(event) {
        window.setTimeout(checkDefault,0);      
    });

    $(window).unload(function(){ //firefox bug fix.
      fake.attr("value","");
    });


    return this;
  }
})(jQuery);
```

this plugin is written by me.

if you want to use this, i think you should use this like that:

```
<label for="register-username">username</label> <input id="register-username" type="text" class="register-ok" />
<label for="register-password">password</label> <input id="register-password" type="password" class="register" />
```

and the JS code to enable:

```
   $("#register-username,register-password").each($(this).inputLabel(););
```

after this you can easily add focus or other styles.

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery, try replacing:

```
'input[type="text"]'
```

with:

```
'#status'
```

Comment: Good thinking, but jQuery's selectors are browser independent. This would apply only to native CSS

Comment: @Paul - You might want to check out this URL. I'm not quite sure if it's what you're after, but they seem to have had the same problem, and have come up with a solution: *http://cf-bill.blogspot.com/2005/05/styling-all-input-typetext-webpage.html*